# In Javascript, replace forEach that involves filtering the same array of objects each time through loop with a left join

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, data-manipulation

Title is a bit wordy, but I have created a fairly good example below that highlights what I am going for:

```
// the array that is being JOINED onto the the main array
var playerArray = [
  { id: 'tom', num: 34, age: 12 }, 
  { id: 'joe', num: 24, age: 14 },
  { id: 'bim', num: 14, age: 15 },
  { id: 'tim', num: 43, age: 16 },
  { id: 'nik', num: 10, age: 17 },
  { id: 'jib', num: 12, age: 87 }
];

// the main array      
var dataArray = [
  { name: 'tom', pts: 24, team: 'bozos', city: 'detroit' },
  { name: 'joe', pts: 14, team: 'bozos', city: 'chicago' },
  { name: 'bim', pts: 34, team: 'kazos', city: 'milkway' },
  { name: 'tim', pts: 51, team: 'kazos', city: 'dragzon' }
];

// loop each row in dataArray, find players number in playerArray, add to dataArray
let thisNum;
dataArray.forEach((currVal, idx, thisArray) => {
  thisNum = playerArray
    .filter(thisP => thisP.id === currVal.name)
    .map(thisP => thisP.num)[0];

  thisArray[idx].num = thisNum;
});

console.log('dataArray: ', dataArray);
0: {name: "tom", pts: 24, team: "bozos", city: "detroit", num: 34}
1: {name: "joe", pts: 14, team: "bozos", city: "chicago", num: 24}
2: {name: "bim", pts: 34, team: "kazos", city: "milkway", num: 14}
3: {name: "tim", pts: 51, team: "kazos", city: "dragzon", num: 43}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So my goal here is to add the correct `num` from `playerArray` onto `dataArray`, and the above example is successful in doing so. However, the actual `dataArray` in my project has ~10000 objects, and the actual `playerArray` has ~2000 objects, and I don't think performing 10000 filters of an object of length 2000 is particularly efficient.

Simply curious if there is a better way to do this in my React app? The above seems not particularly efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it more efficient you should make the `playerArray` an object so you don't need all the `filter` and `map` business. Then you can just look it up in constant time rather than searching the the players for each element of the dataArray:

```js
var playerArray = [
    { id: 'tom', num: 34, age: 12 }, 
    { id: 'joe', num: 24, age: 14 },
    { id: 'bim', num: 14, age: 15 },
    { id: 'tim', num: 43, age: 16 },
    { id: 'nik', num: 10, age: 17 },
    { id: 'jib', num: 12, age: 87 }
  ];
  
// the main array      
var dataArray = [
    { name: 'tom', pts: 24, team: 'bozos', city: 'detroit' },
    { name: 'joe', pts: 14, team: 'bozos', city: 'chicago' },
    { name: 'bim', pts: 34, team: 'kazos', city: 'milkway' },
    { name: 'tim', pts: 51, team: 'kazos', city: 'dragzon' }
  ];

// make an object keyed to id
let playerObject = playerArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item
    return obj
}, {})
 
// now you can use the name to look up the id:
dataArray.forEach(item => item.num = playerObject[item.name].num)

console.log(dataArray)
```

Comment: consider yourself my hero - thanks appreciate this a ton

Answer (score 1):

Create an object from `playerArray` so that you don't have to loop through it everytime.

```
var playerObject = {};
playerArray.forEach(player => {
  playerObject[player.id] = player.num;
});

dataArray.forEach(dataPlayer => {
  dataPlayer.num = playerObject[dataPlayer.name];
});
```